# Where does request.get_host() get it's information from? (How to make it have the name of the host, not the IP?)

Tags: django

I have a django instance being served on a virtual machine (not administered by me), using apache and mod_wsgi.

The value that I get from `request.get_host()`  (and `build_absolute_uri()`) is the internal network IP address of the virtual machine, rather than the internet DNS host name that I use to make the HTTP request.

What configuration outside django would need to be done to make django think it's host is the external host name?

(At the moment I have a hack in settings.py where I write the host name and use it to construct urls etc, as a workaround).

Comment: you get with ``request.META['HTTP_HOST']`` the domainname, is it what you want?

Answer (score 5):

If you have the django setting `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` set, then django will look for a request header named `X-Forwarded-Host` and use that.

If the above doesn't pan out, then django uses the `Host` request header.

If neither of the above work (and this should be rare), django uses the WSGI environment variable `SERVER_NAME` which will most likely be the IPv4/v6 address of the socket that your python application server is listening on.

Most likely, you are running a reverse proxy server in front of your python server, and the proxy is altering the host header of the original request. If this is the case, you may want to set settings.USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST in django, and tell your proxy to pass the original host header in `X-Forwarded-Host`.

Answer (score 2):

I would like little bit to extend the answer of ender672

When you send request to Django, in request object you have META arrtibute (request.META)
That attribute is a dictionary that include a lot of key/value. Here is example of META in my case:
[image]

Look at the end of the picture. You see HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST? That key had been generated automatically. It will always appear here, unless you will start to change source code of request class.

So server knows his external IP (that you used to access to server), but it doesn't use it inside Django, because by default `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = False`. And in that scenario it will use request.META.HTTP_HOST, you can see that it picture above

That's why you need to add new line into Django settings:

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
```

After that it will start to replace it's internal address by external address.